# Wrong data on SQL query

Tags: sql, join

My requirement is to fetch details from two tables `REPORT_API_USAGE` & `REPORT_API_PAGES`. I need to get `TERMNAME`, `COUNT(TERMNAME)` from `REPORT_API_USAGE` and `COUNT(CTYPE)` for both `event` and `download` from `REPORT_API_PAGES`. Both table has common field `termid`. The requirement is to get `TERMNAME`, `COUNT(TERMNAME)` with related events and file-download.

[image]

[image]

[image]

There is only one `TERMID` `24` in `REPORT_API_PAGES` With `CTYPE` as `download`. So the result should be `Face-to-Face Learning    1   0   1`

I have a page `Face-to-Face Learning` with `TERMID'`24`. I have added an event and document with reference of`Face-to-Face Learning`. Once i viewed`Face-to-Face Learning`page,`COUNT(TERMNAME)`will store the page hit value in`REPORT_API_USAGE`table. Once the event and document pages are viewed,`REPORT_API_USAGE`will store the details with`TERMID`reference. I need to create a report of views. Need to get`Face-to-Face Learning` view count with related event and document hits.

Comment: Please share your tables structure, some sample data and the result you are trying to get for that data.

Comment: Also which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

You have two rows with **termname**='Face-to-Face Learning' in table **report_api_usage** therefore returned two lines.

You should use:

```
select ap.termname,
count(distinct ap.termname) as tot,
count(distinct ai.ctype) as event,
sum(case when ai.ctype = 'event' then 1 else 0 end) as page
from ...
```

I don't understand what you want count.. If you want count how many **repoet_api_pages** have **ctype** 'event' or 'download' use follows query:

```
select ap.termname,
count(ap.termname) as tot, -- if it total count rows in table report_api_usage, if you need unique count use distinct inside count function
sum(case when ai.ctype = 'download' then 1 else 0 end) as page_download
sum(case when ai.ctype = 'event' then 1 else 0 end) as page_event
from ...
```

Comment: You can't have follows result: Face-to-Face Learning    1   0   1. Because you have ai.ctype ='download'. Correct result: Face-to-Face Learning    1   1   0

Comment: Yes. How can i modify my query to get the counts of  `event` & `page` related to `Face-to-Face Learning` from `REPORT_API_PAGES`.

Comment: HAYMbl4...In my query, i added the condition for both `event` & `download`. Is that right?. There is only one `download` for `Face-to-Face Learning`. So the expected result is

Comment: I edited my answer, if it does not help you, please correct purpose of the your query

Comment: My requirement is added to question.

Answer (score 0):

Finlay i found the expensive query.

`SELECT  AIP.TERMID, 
                    (select count(RAU.TERMNAME) FROM REPORT_API_USAGE RAU WHERE RAU.TERMID = AIP.TERMID AND RAU.VOCID = 4) as page_views,
                    (select sum(count(RAU.TERMNAME)) FROM REPORT_API_USAGE RAU WHERE  RAU.VOCID = 4
                    and RAU.TERMID in (select AIP.TERMID from REPORT_API_PAGES AIP GROUP BY  AIP.TERMID) group by RAU.VOCID) as page_views_sum,
          (select sum(count(AIP2.TERMID)) from REPORT_API_PAGES AIP2 join REPORT_API_USAGE RAU ON (RAU.TERMID = AIP2.TERMID AND RAU.VOCID = 4) where aip2.ctype = 'download' GROUP by AIP2.termid) as download_sum,
          (select sum(count(AIP2.TERMID)) from REPORT_API_PAGES AIP2 join REPORT_API_USAGE RAU ON (RAU.TERMID = AIP2.TERMID AND RAU.VOCID = 4) where aip2.ctype = 'event' GROUP by AIP2.termid) as event_sum,
                    COUNT(case when aip.ctype = 'download' then 1 else null end) as page_download,
                    COUNT(case when aip.ctype = 'event' then 1 else null end) as page_event 
                    from REPORT_API_PAGES AIP
                    GROUP BY  AIP.TERMID`